# "Unexpected shutdown" message on Hyper-V guest machines

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, unexpected-shutdown

We have a couple of Dell Poweredge servers running Hyper-V. Both host machines and the guest VMs are using Server 2008 R2 Enterprise with Service Pack 1 installed. The guest machines were built as VMs rather than converted from physical servers. Whenever a guest VM is restarted we get the "unexpected shutdown" dialog next time we log on.

This happens whether we reboot the guest from an RDP session, do it through the Hyper-V manager or if the host machine is restarted.

I've double checked that the integration services "disk" has been inserted and run successfully and have done so since SP1 was installed on the host. Under the integration services settings for the guest VM the relevant box is ticked for Operating System Shutdown.

I've looked at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207413%28v=ws.10%29.aspx and checked that the version of integration services is the same on host and client - 6.1.7601.17514

Does anyone have any suggestions what to check next or why this might be happening? Thanks.

Comment: strangely enough lately we are seeing the same issue on both hypervisors that we use esxi 4,5 and hyper-v. Not all the time just more frequently then in the past.  And yes the guest are all w2k8r2sp1

Comment: I should also say that the shutdown delay has not been exceeded so they should be clean but they are not.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old issue but I've come across with this with VMs running Server 2008 R2 after migrating the host to Hyper-V 2012 R2

Check if all device drivers were upgraded. Please see more detailed instructions at http://alexappleton.net/post/69391495030/two-unknown-devices-in-windows-server-2008-r2-under

Answer (score 0):

The "unexpected shutdown" message means that not all the writes to the disk were flushed before the VM turned off or rebooted.  I can't tell you why this occurred from what you've written, but I can suggest that you look for reasons within the VMs that the storage might be doing strange things (like odd anti-malware packages, etc.) or outside the VM (like a RAID controller or SAN) that may be skipping flushes.